# Can I pay for the data transfer even if an s3 bucket isn't specified as requester pays?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm going to copy an entire bucket (50TB) and would like to make sure I pay for the transfer costs and the owner doesn't get hit with a big bill.  Can I just specify the --request-payer requester flag and take the tab for transfer or is that only possible if the owner has explicitly made the bucket as requester pays?

Comment: When you say "copy an entire bucket", are you saying that you will **download** the contents to your computer, or are you **copying the bucket to another S3 bucket**? If the latter, are you copying within the same AWS region?

Comment: I was referring to copying to another S3 bucket.  I suppose it would be a different AWS region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is that only possible if the owner has explicitly made the bucket as requester pays?

Yes. The bucket must be set to `Requester Pays`. If its not set, then the owner misconfigured the bucket or simply does not care about the cost.

If the bucket is public, then `Requester Pays` can't be set to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying data between Amazon S3 buckets in the **same region**, then there is no Data Transfer charge. You would only be charged for **Requests** ($0.0004 per 1000 requests).

If you are transferring the data **between S3 buckets in different regions**, then **Data Transfer** (~$0.02 per GB depending on region) *would* be charged. I think it would be charged to the **bucket owner** since Data Transfer is charged for *Outbound* data flows.

Comment: This is really useful to know!  Thanks.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. If you are copying data between S3 buckets in the same region but are in a different AWS account, you may be charged. If you are in a different account make sure to setup a S3 gateway endpoint

Comment: @Almenon The data would only pass through an S3 Gateway Endpoint if it is being **downloaded** and then **uploaded** to a resource in a VPC. If the data is being **copied** between buckets (eg using calls to `CopyObject` or using the AWS CLI that calls `CopyObject`), then there is no data going through the VPC and hence no Data Transfer charge or VPC Egress (1c/GB) charge for the data.

Comment: Good clarification, thanks